'Multiple bindings for fabric have been detected' error while using caliper
I want to use Hyperledger Fabric v3.0.0 with Caliper v0.6.0 to evaluate the performance. I am on Ubuntu 22.04. I completely rebuilt the Fabric network and followed the exact same steps as described on the caliper website (link), but I still get the below error when I start the benchmark with the following command:  npx caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-networkconfig networks/networkConfig.yaml --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test
The error:
2024.12.03-13:47:32.435 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]    Set workspace path: /home/umit/Desktop/HLF-3-0-0/caliper-workspace
2024.12.03-13:47:32.437 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]    Set benchmark configuration path: /home/umit/Desktop/HLF-3-0-0/caliper-workspace/benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml
2024.12.03-13:47:32.437 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]    Set network configuration path: /home/umit/Desktop/HLF-3-0-0/caliper-workspace/networks/networkConfig.yaml
2024.12.03-13:47:32.437 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]    Set SUT type: fabric
2024.12.03-13:47:33.155 info  [caliper] [benchmark-validator]   No observer specified, will default to `none`
2024.12.03-13:47:33.155 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Starting benchmark flow
2024.12.03-13:47:33.157 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Skipping start commands due to benchmark flow conditioning
2024.12.03-13:47:33.159 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Skipping initialization phase due to benchmark flow conditioning
2024.12.03-13:47:33.160 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Skipping install smart contract phase due to benchmark flow conditioning
2024.12.03-13:47:40.344 error [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Error while performing "test" step: Error: Multiple bindings for fabric have been detected, you need to unbind one or more to ensure only a single bind is present to continue
    at _determineInstalledNodeSDKandVersion (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-fabric/lib/FabricConnectorFactory.js:52:19)
    at CaliperEngine.connectorFactory [as adapterFactory] (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-fabric/lib/FabricConnectorFactory.js:132:17)
    at CaliperEngine.run (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-core/lib/manager/caliper-engine.js:149:64)
    at LaunchManager.handler (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/lib/launch/lib/launchManager.js:81:43)
    at module.exports.handler (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/lib/launch/launchManagerCommand.js:46:44)
    at Object.runCommand (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:240:40)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1154:41)
    at Object.runCommand (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:198:30)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1154:41)
    at Object.get [as argv] (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1088:21)
2024.12.03-13:47:40.345 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Skipping end command due to benchmark flow conditioning
2024.12.03-13:47:40.345 error [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]    Benchmark execution failed with error code: 6
Usage:
 caliper launch manager --caliper-bind-sut fabric:2.2 [other options]

Options:
  --help, -h           Show usage information  [boolean]
  --version            Show version information  [boolean]
  --caliper-bind-sut   The name and version of the platform to bind to  [string]
  --caliper-bind-cwd   The working directory for performing the SDK install  [string]
  --caliper-bind-args  Additional arguments to pass to "npm install". Use the "=" notation when setting this parameter  [string]
  --caliper-bind-file  Yaml file to override default (supported) package versions when binding an SDK  [string]

Error: Benchmark execution failed with error code: 6
    at LaunchManager.handler (/home/umit/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-cli/lib/launch/lib/launchManager.js:89:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


I am writing this for those who will encounter this problem in the future. This solution led me to another problem but it does not give this error anymore. The problem is caused by the inability to isolate some files when working with more than one hyperledger fabric version. When I tracked the source of the error, I saw that the fabric-network folder in the node_modules folder caused this error. Because it is not used in Hyperledger Fabric v2.4 and later versions (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-network) and Fabric Gateway needs to be used instead. If you delete the relevant folder or adjust your runtime environment accordingly, this problem will be solved.
